# jQuery 'this' scope in event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, this, jquery-events

I am unable to access parent object with in the event handler of the object!

I am creating a widget:

```
(function( $ ) {

  $.widget('cs.window',{

     _create:function(){
       var me = this;
       this.append('<div class="close">X</div>');
       var close = this.element.find('.close');
       close.bind('click',function(){
        alert($(this));// this is referring event handler here
                       //but how to access `me` object here
        me.element.hide();//I want to achieve this, about but its saying me is undefined
      });
     }
  });

}(jQuery));
```

How to use `me` object in the click event handler?

Comment: If you look at jquery click you'll see some great examples: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @PaulS. I tried but saying me is undefined.

Comment: @RamaRaoM log the value of `this` and of `me` when inside `_create` and see what you get. It may be that `this` is _undefined_ there (can happen depending on how the function is ultimately invoked)

Comment: @RamaRaoM: `me` should not be `undefined` in the above, not if `this` wasn't `undefined` when `_create` was called (which probably wasn't the case, or you'd've seen a different error, during `_create`).

Comment: @PaulS. No,this is not undefined out of the event.Its referring current widget object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind a function with `this._on` then the `this` inside the callback is the widget itself. Try:

```
this._on(close, {
    click: function(){ this.element.hide(); }
});
```